# How to set up a Django project under windows?

Tags: django, windows

I'm trying to set up a django project but I fail.

- First of all I have a Windows 8 machine.
- My PATH variable is that:

`C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;-vm 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe`

- When I open PyCharm for example and type `import django` there comes no error message
- Then, in the officialy tutorial "Writing your first Django app" they say I have to create a project with this command `django-admin.py startproject mysite`

I tried this via command prompt with administrative privileges under Windows from these folders:

`C:\Python34\Scripts`

&

`C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\bin`

In both folders I can find a `django-admin.py`.

There comes no error message, it just rushes through and is not creating any folders. What am I missing here?

The output of the command prompt is this:

```
C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\bin>django-admin.py startproject myApp
Usage: django-admin.py subcommand [options] [args]

Options:
  -v VERBOSITY, --verbosity=VERBOSITY
                        Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output,
                        2=verbose output, 3=very verbose output
  --settings=SETTINGS   The Python path to a settings module, e.g.
                        "myproject.settings.main". If this isn't provided, the
                        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable will be
                        used.
  --pythonpath=PYTHONPATH
                        A directory to add to the Python path, e.g.
                        "/home/djangoprojects/myproject".
  --traceback           Raise on exception
  --no-color            Don't colorize the command output.
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

Type 'django-admin.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    runfcgi
    runserver
    shell
    sql
    sqlall
    sqlclear
    sqlcustom
    sqldropindexes
    sqlflush
    sqlindexes
    sqlinitialdata
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    syncdb
    test
    testserver
    validate
Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly conf
igured (error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured
. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
 settings.configure() before accessing settings.).
```

Comment: That kind of output is telling you how to use the command, since you used it incorrectly. It is also telling you how to find help for specific subcommands, which I'm guessing is what you need.

Comment: First you need to install django over pip. (Have you done it?) The second thing I found in your post is this: 'C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\bin>django-admin.py startproject myApp'. 
With this command you try to make the project into 'C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\bin'. You should go into your folder(where the project should be) and then run 'django-admin.py startproject myApp'

Comment: Okay, I found this video on Youtube which helps me. Now it works all fine. (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPmkl4jtYgA&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzSH9ylikCRyki_Bi6avmltQ&index=2)